# Successfully delete an object in mongodb using findByIdAndDelete but returns an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am using `` axios.delete(`http://localhost:5001/agenda/` + item._id) `` to delete the item in an array. The schema looks like:

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  startDateTime: Date,
  endDateTime: Date,
  classes: String
});
```

In the server-side, I have

```
router.route("/:id").delete((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  Event.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    .then(() => res.jason("Event deleted."))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

After I run this program, I have `{ id: 'aff2187e-f28a-38f8-1cb1-3cbeab97d721' }` in the terminal, which is the value of req.params. The web page shows `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 400` and I did not see "Event deleted." appeared in the console. But when I check the database or refresh the page, it successfully deletes.

After searching online, I try to change `req.params.id` to `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)`, but it does not work, since there is some restriction for object id.

I have no idea why it has been deleted and at the same time it returns an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you misspelled `res.json` as `res.jason`

And that causes the code to go into the `.catch` and return the error.